# Connection error while deploying Cassandra v2.2.8 in Bluemix

Tags: cassandra, containers, ibm-cloud

I have created an IBM container with Cassandra v2.2.8 on Bluemix. When starting it, I get the following error:

```
TINFO  09:20:56 DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be 
mmap, indexAccessMode is mmap   
FINFO  09:20:56 Global memtable on-heap threshold is enabled at 1996MB   
GINFO  09:20:56 Global memtable off-heap threshold is enabled at 1996MB   
ŽException (org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException) 
encountered during startup: Unknown listen_address '172.32.0.4 172.32.0.4'   
/Unknown listen_address '172.32.0.4 172.32.0.4'   
dERROR 09:20:56 Exception encountered during startup: 
Unknown listen_address '172.32.0.4 172.32.0.4'
```

I see that a similar issue is present in Cassandra v2.2:
https://github.com/docker-library/cassandra/pull/77

How do I implement the solution mentioned in the above link in a Bluemix environment?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you will need to set an environment variable for CASSANDRA_LISTEN_ADDRESS and possibly CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS.

I'm not sure if you can get away with just setting 127.0.0.1 (I haven't used cassandra before), but if you can't, the best thing to do would be to request an IP address before deploying the container and then pass that IP address as the value for the listen address when you start the container.  Then bind that container to the IP address.

Hope this helps.